# jQuery setTimeout with animation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have some set CSS that after 2 seconds I want to revert to their defined positions.

I am using this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $("div").css("z-index", "");
        $("div").css("height", "");
        $("div").css("width", "");
        $("div").css("marginLeft", "");
        $("div").css("marginTop", "");
}, 2000 );
```

So what this does is basically sends five different divs back to places all over the page after 2 seconds. On load they are doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("div").css("z-index", "");
        $("#tablet,#phone,#television,#web,#social,#fusion").css({
            width: "500px",
            height: "350px",
            marginLeft: "30%",
            marginTop: "25px",
        }, 750);
});
```

I was wondering if you guys know how to animate the events after 2 seconds. Right now its just happening fast but I would like it to be an animation back to their initial states.

I have been using this to animate the 5 divs all into one area onclick:

```
$("#tablet,#phone,#television,#web,#social,#fusion").animate({
            width: "500px",
            height: "350px",
            marginLeft: "30%",
            marginTop: "25px",
        }, 750);
```

Thanks!

Comment: So is your setTimeout not working? Have you tried jQuery delay()? [delay documentaion](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Answer (score 1):

Call me crazy but it looks like you have the answer to your own question here.
You clearly already know how ot use jquery animate, so why not use that instead of just redefining the css in your setTimeout?

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $("#tablet,#phone,#television,#web,#social,#fusion").animate({
            width: "0px",
            height: "0px",
            marginLeft: "0%",
            marginTop: "0px",
        }, 750);
}, 2000 );
```

Did I read your question incorrectly? Or is it that you don't want your elements to have a 0px width and height but you want those css declarations to be removed entirely?

**EDIT**

Ok, so as per your explanation you want them to go back to their already defined states. I presume you mean BEFORE the onload statement that redefines their position, right? Does this mean that you are operating with the understanding that the previous state is not known and is abstract and you want to know how to fetch that information? Or do you mean very simply that you do know the state you want it to return to and just don't know how to tell it to animate there?

css file:

```
#div{
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-top:20%;
}
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div').css({marginTop:'50%', marginLeft:'50%'});


    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#div").animate({
            marginLeft: "20%",
            marginTop: "20%",
        }, 750);
    }, 2000 );
});
```

So that would be if you knew the desired css to return to. If you did NOT know, you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var div = new Array();
    div.push($('#div').css('margin-top'));
    div.push($('#div').css('margin-left'));

    $('#div').css({marginTop:'50%', marginLeft:'50%'});


    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#div").animate({
            marginLeft: div[0],
            marginTop: div[1],
        }, 750);
    }, 2000 );
});
```

Comment: No. I need them to go back to their already defined states. Not 0's. For example in my css I'm defining the following: #television {
    width: 20%;
    height: 350px;
    z-index: -3;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 50px;
} and on load I have it go to the defined width: "500px",
            height: "350px",
            marginLeft: "30%",
            marginTop: "25px", I'm using the  " " to tell them to go back to their orignal states. This is sort of tough to explain.

Comment: I don't think " " tells them to go back to original state. That says to wipe the attribute value. If it happens to look like what you want it might be accidental. Nevermind that though - I'll modify my answer to ask more in depth...

Comment: For .css " " tells them to go back the original state. I was wondering if there is similar solution for .animate

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a bunch of elements in "natural" positions on the page. You want to move them to a new position, then later return them to their respective initial positions.

Putting aside the question of animation, one solution would be to capture each element's initial position and other attributes, and store that information on the element itself using `data()`. In your "reset" function, you could then reference those data to reset each element. So, something like this (untested):

```
// in your $(document).ready() handler:
$('div').each( function () {
  var original = {
    w: $(this).width(),
    h: $(this).height(),
    o: $(this).offset()
  };
  $(this).data('orig', original);
});
```

Each `div` now knows where it came from. You then move them around as you wish. When it's time to return them:

```
var backToOriginal = function() {
  $('div').each( function () {
    var $d = $(this).data('orig');
    $(this).animate({
      'top': $d.o.top,
      'left': $d.o.left,
      'width': $d.w,
      'height': $d.h
    });
  });
};
setTimeout(backToOriginal, 1000); // animate to original position after 1 sec
```

Change animation and delays to taste.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/LQyeh/

Initially the elements are randomly dispersed (in your case, they'd be in their natural positions according to your markup). When you trigger the routine, they're mutated and moved to a single position. After a delay, they smoothly return to their initial position and size.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I have relied on the clone method of jQuery. You can hide the original element and use the clone for your animation. To restor the original just destroy the clone and unhide the original.

[Clone Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)